# Export MYSQL to CSV leaving empty fields

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to export a mysql query to csv. I have it working, the only thing is  it's not putting the empty fields in there. I them separate by pipes, |. I need to be able to download the query and upload it somewhere else, so I need it to export the empty fields along with it. Here is my current export code:

```
<?php


$from = $_REQUEST['from'];
$to = $_REQUEST['to'];
$filename = "APGE_ELEC_" . $to;
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'".csv"');

    $hostname = ""; //SET SERVER/HOSTNAME
    $dbusername = ""; //SET DATABASE USERNAME
    $dbname = ""; //SET DATABASE NAME
    $dbpassword = ""; //SET DATABASE USERNAME

$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $dbusername, $dbpassword) 
  or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

$selected = mysql_select_db($dbname,$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select Data Base");


$query = "SELECT * FROM v88374 WHERE date >= DATE_FORMAT('" . $from . "', '%Y%m%d') AND date <=  DATE_FORMAT('" . $to . "', '%Y%m%d')";


$export = mysql_query ($query ) or die ( "Sql error : " . mysql_error( ) );

$fields = mysql_num_fields ( $export );

for ( $i = 0; $i < $fields; $i++ )
{
    $header .= mysql_field_name( $export , $i ) ."|" . "\t";
}

while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    $line = '';
    foreach( $row as $value )
    {                                            
        if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
        {
            $value = "\t";
        }
        else
        {
            $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
            $value = $value . '|' . "\t";
        }
        $line .= $value;
    }
    $data .= trim( $line ) . "\n";
}
$data = str_replace( "\r" , "" , $data );

if ( $data == "" )
{
    $data = "\n(0) Records Found!\n"; 

}

print "$header\n$data";


exit();


?>
```

I hope its not a huge fix. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: It'd be much easier to use `fputcsv`, which will allow you to specify a delimiter and then write the csv to a file, which will be properly formatted. Also, mysql_* functions are deprecated, and really should move to `PDO` or `mysqli`.

Comment: can you give me an example of using the fputcsv?

Comment: Sure, I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the mistake is in here:

```
    if ( ( !isset( $value ) ) || ( $value == "" ) )
    {
        $value = "\t";
    }
    else
    {
        $value = str_replace( '"' , '""' , $value );
        $value = $value . '|' . "\t";
    }
    $line .= $value;
```

When $value is empty you make it a tab and add it without a pipe, the stuff in the else statement is not executed.

Also you have a major security issue with your query, so unless it is for personal use only and some sanitation to the query.

```
$from = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['from']);
$to = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['to']);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not simply do

```
SELECT whatever
FROM your_table
INTO OUTFILE '/directory/file.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

?

And from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html):

> ... if the MySQL client software is installed on the remote machine, you can instead use a client command such as mysql -e "SELECT ..." > file_name to generate the file on the client host

Answer (score 1):

To use fputcsv, try this:

```
$fp = fopen('your_file_name.csv','w');
fputcsv($fp,$fields,'|'); // add in your header row
while( $row = mysql_fetch_row( $export ) )
{
    if($row != NULL)
        fputcsv($fp,$row,'|'); // Each row is already an array, so you just need to export it here
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I'm getting Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array. null given. What do I do with the $header exactly?

Comment: I changed header to fields since that's where you're putting the fields directly from the query. Interesting that $row is null from your while loop. I'm going to tweak that line as well.

Comment: Getting close I think. Sorry for all the questions. if I change it to your changes above, it now downloads but just keeps downloading..I had to stop it at 50MB. Is that weird?

Comment: Depends on the amount of your data. Check the file so far to see if it's okay, and then check to see how many rows your query returns.

Comment: I removed the null on the while, and added a check below. That should take care of the null error and large data.